# Show that $U(R) \to U(R/J(R)) $ is an epimorphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

$\textbf{The question is as follows:}$

> > Show that the canonical homomorphism $R \to R/J(R)$ maps the group of units $U(R)$ onto the group of units $U(R/J(R))$.

$\textbf{Some observations:}$

We need to show that the following arguments are equivalent for ring $R$ and ieals $I$, $J$ and Jacobson radical $J(R):$

$ \rm 1)\quad J \subset J(R)$ $~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~$ i.e.  $ \rm J$ lies in every max ideal of $ \rm R$.

$ \rm 2)\quad 1 + J \subset U\,$ $~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~$ i.e.  $ \rm 1 + j$ is a unit for every  $ \rm j \in J$.

$ \rm 3)\quad I < 1 \Rightarrow I + J < 1\,$$~~~~~~~$ i.e. proper ideals survive in $ \rm R/J$.

This implies that all the nonunits in $ \rm R$ survive as nonunits in $ \rm R/J,$
so the only units in $ \rm R/J$ are those that are images of units in $ \rm R$ and we will be done!

Can someone help me in showing this equivalence?

Thanks!

Comment: The ideal $\;J(R)\;$ is not, in general, nilpotent, even if we take $\;R\;$ to be a commutative ring, so you cannot show "first"...unless you're making further assumptions.

Comment: @DonAntonio Many thanks! But there is no assumption on $R$, else that being an associative ring with identity 1!! So you think in this case it is not possible to show that the sequence is exact?

Comment: As far as I see it, no...unless there's some assumption on commutativity, Arthinian or stuff. Take into account that, *in general*, $\;x\in J(R)\iff \forall\,r,s\in R\;,\;\;1+rxs\in U(R)\;$ . We can simplify this a little if we talk about **left or right** ideals and etc., and we can simplify this **a lot** if $\;R\;$ is commutative...but without further info I can't see how...

Comment: @DonAntonio Many thanks! Let me change the question a bit.

Comment: You mean here *two sided* units, right? One must be careful with sides if commutativity isn't given...

Comment: @DonAntonio Many thanks! Yes I think it should be two sided. But it has not be clarified in the question. But let us take it two sided.

Answer (score 4):

**Any** ring homomorphism $\;\phi:R\to S\;$ maps (left, right double-sided) units to (l,r,ds) units, since

$$u\in U(R)\implies\exists\,r\in R\;\;s.t.\;\;ru=1\implies1=\phi1=\phi(ru)=\phi(r)\phi(u)\implies\phi(u)\in U(S)$$

You can generalize the above to left/double-sided units and etc. Observe that I undertake implicitly the important agreement that homomorphism between unital rings maps one to one... Now, some highlights:

(1)$\to$(2): Suppose that for some $\;j\in J\;$ we have that $\;1+j\notin U(R)\implies 1+i\in M\;$ , for some maximal (left, right, two sided...) ideal $\;M\le R\;$ . Get now your contradiction

(2)$\to$(3): suppose now that $\;I\lneqq R\;$ but $\;I+J=R/J\;$ , then

$$\forall\,r\in R\;\exists\,i_r\in I,\,j_r\in J\;\;s.t.\;\;r=i_r+j_r$$

But there exists a maximal ideal $\;M_I\;$ s.t. $\;I\le M_I\;$ , and since $\;J\le M_I\;$  we get

$$r=i_r+j_r\in M_I+M_I=M_I$$

Since the above is true **also for** $\;r=u\in U(R)\;$ , get now your contradiction.

**Added on request** Suppose now (3) is true for some ideal $\;J\le R\;$ , but (1) isn't true. Then, there exists some maximal ideal $\;M\le R\;$ s.t. $\;J\nsubseteq M\;$ . This means that $J+M=R\;$ since $\;M\lneqq J+M\;$ ...and this contradicts (3) !

Comment: Many thanks for your knowledgeable answer! But I am so sorry I have many questions? Can you please let me know that how the arguments in $(1)\to(2)$ and $(2)\to(3)$ contradicts our assumption? And how did you get $\;1+j\notin U(R)\implies 1+j\in M\;?$ And can you also please let me know how to go from $(3)$ to $(1)$?

Comment: @Nikita In the first part we assume (1) is true but (2) isn't. From $\;1+i=m\in M\;$ we get that $\;1=m-i\in M\;$ (why?), and *this is* the contradiction. In te second part we assume (2) is true but (3) isn't, so we get that for any $\;u\in U(R)\;, u\in M_I\;$ , which is also a contradiction (why? Because then $\;M=R...!$)

Comment: Many thanks for your complete answer! Sorry can I ask a question? Does this equivalence really implies the result which has been asked in the question? Can you please explain it for me a bit? Thanks!

Comment: @Nikita Of course it does: it is the very first part of my answer!